# Flag changed to "harassment, bigotry, or abuse", causing it to be declined, when I didn't flag it as such

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, declined-flags, comment-flags, code-of-conduct

I flagged a comment earlier today for violating the Code of Conduct. When I flagged it, the dialog was different from what I see now. Now, I see:

> - It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
>   The comment violates our Code of Conduct.
> - It's unfriendly or unkind.
>   The comment violates our Code of Conduct.
> - It's no longer needed.
>   This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.
> - Something else.
>   A problem not listed above. Try to be as specific as possible.

When I flagged it, the first two options didn't exist as separate options, there was only one option to choose for messages violating the CoC, so I picked that reason.

When I look at my flags now, I see the flag was declined but the message removed. The flag reason changed to "harassment, bigotry, or abuse". The comment in question definitely wasn't harassment, bigotry, or abuse, it was just unfriendly, so the moderator was right to decline this flag.

I do not appreciate putting a flag on my name that isn't mine. I did flag that comment, but changing the reason turned the flag into something both SE and I consider wrong, and I do not appreciate the system falsely telling me that's what I did.

Can this flag be fixed to accurately represent how I reported it?

Comment: Quick note: the flags changed at 17:08:22 UTC today - that's about 18 minutes after your flag was declined. Doesn't change the fact that your history was altered, but does mean the change in wording didn't have any influence on the outcome.

Comment: @Shog9 Huh. That's weird, thanks for checking that. I suppose that turns this into two questions.

Comment: It seems the splitting of the old "rude or abusive" flag was carried out by repurposing it to become the "abusive" one, while a brand new "rude" flag was created. I agree it would be better to have both as proper new flags, while leaving the old, inactive one as it was for the sake of having accurate historical records.

Comment: @duplode I concur. I checked my flagging history and the old "not constructive" and "too chatty" flags were still there with their old names, so those ones have apparently not returned.

Comment: Unbelievable. Poor moderators, to have to decide what is "unfriendly" or "unkind". It's going to become impossible to keep the site on-target.

Comment: @Cindy Calling this unbelievable is unkind to the people who designed this flagging dialog. Flagged as such (jk ofc).

Comment: @Erik <VBG> (And I'd leave it at that if such a short comment were allowed...)

Comment: (I'm glad we have "no longer needed" again ...)

Answer (score 1):

> Can this flag be fixed to accurately represent how I reported it?

I wouldn't worry about how the wording of the flag shows in your flag history. Flags aren't publicly visible, and moderators are (hopefully!) in-tune enough with changes to the site that they will understand that retroactively-renamed flags had different wording at the time that you raised them. If a *close reason* had its wording retroactively changed, such that wording you had never selected were being exposed to the public internet and attributed to you, I'd agree that that was unacceptable and in need of fixing. But in this case, it seems to me that there's no real harm done; while it's somewhat inelegant, I don't personally see any need for it to be fixed.

Comment: One tangible consequence is that any attempt to analyse flagging data will have to handle pre-split and post-split "abusive" flags separately. Whether that justifies changing the schema to take that into account is up for discussion (but I'd like that to happen).

Comment: "and moderators are (hopefully!) in-tune enough with changes to the site" -- If that's the case, why was my flag declined but the comment removed? That suggests to me that the moderator thought the comment should be deleted, but I should have picked a different flag reason, when there wasn't any other I could have used. Still, whether it's public or private, it's simply not true. That should be reason enough for me not to want to see it.

Comment: Close reasons with a wording you never selected can get attributed to you: the closed question shows the names of all the close voters, but only the most popular close reason.

Comment: @HugoRune yeah, and I find that objectionable too, and wish it would be fixed. But that's another fight.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the cure is probably worse than the disease here.

The "abusive" flag has been around in some form for over 8 years - but the actual *description* has changed multiple times. Moderators have always been expected to use their judgement when handling these, weighing the value of the comment against the cost of keeping off-putting language on the site - and that's led to a fair bit of controversy not to mention inconsistency.

*Hopefully*, the introduction of the "unfriendly" flag helps here; arguably any abusive comment is *also* unfriendly, and of course many unfriendly comments could be (and have been) considered abusive... But having a separate flag may help people who would've refrained from flagging in the past to become more comfortable with the idea that such things *should* be flagged.

That said... It's still going to be a judgement call. And... sometimes moderators will disagree that a given comment is problematic *no matter what the flag is called*, which is what happened here: your flag was handled *before* the name change went into effect.

Replacing the flag instead of renaming would've [kept history consistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313543/why-was-the-display-of-prior-no-longer-needed-comment-flags-retroactively-chan/313549#313549) (this time... It'd still have been wrong for all past name changes). But at the cost of having to update a lot more code to support it, and the risk that goes along with that: it's worth noting that the "unfriendly" flag straight-up didn't work in many places for a few days after it was rolled out for precisely this reason.

In 6 months, most of this will be ancient history. Best look to the future.

Comment: Oh, I don't mind that the description slightly changes, that's not what I meant. My apologies if I was not sufficiently clear about that. What I mind is that going by the descriptions at the time I flagged, the "abusive" flag had been removed entirely. I hadn't flagged anything as abusive, regardless of its description, except apparently for an implementation detail that I could not be expected to have known about. I'm not asking for all historic descriptions of the flag types to be preserved. I'm asking for this flag type to be edited to "unfriendly", as that's how I flagged it.

Comment: Ah... Unfortunately, I have no way to do that. If the comment is still around, you could raise the new flag on it now though.

Comment: The flag may have been declined, but the comment did get removed.

Comment: Ah, you did mention that before, sorry

Comment: I have been thinking about this but I am still not sure how to deal with this. I am thankful for you taking the time to take a look at this, and I hope you do not mind if I do not accept any answer unless at some later time I manage to actually accept the situation.

Comment: Totally understandable, @hvd